# how to get a copy of global costmap from move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, navfn, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am writing a package which needs to use global costmap for its calculations. this package does not implement BaseGlobalPlanner, because it is not the task of the package. the global costmap is private variable of move_base and i did not find any way to access it in another package. so my qestion is how do i get the global costmap from move_base for my calculations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11322/how-to-get-a-copy-of-global-costmap-from-move_base/) by [harmish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1124/harmish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the CPU cost isn't too high, you can also just instantiate a Costmap2DROS object in your node.  You need to give it the appropriate ROS parameter definitions — look in the move base launch files and http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d to see examples.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1